# C# Entity Framework, how to check a boolean field on any database set?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using .net core 6 with postgresql and entity framework core.

I am looking to dynamically check any DBSet for whether the field Disabled which is on all of my tables is true/false dependent on a param being passed in as includeDisabled. What is the best way to approach this? So far I have the following to be added onto any queries from the DBSet or IQueryable but it's not working. What am I doing wrong here?

```
public static IQueryable<T> NotDisabled<T>(this IQueryable<T> list, bool includeDisabled = false){
            if(includeDisabled)
                return list;
            var body = Expression.Equal(Expression.PropertyOrField(typeof(T), "Disabled"), Expression.Constant(true));
            var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body);
            return list.Where(predicate);
        }
```

Comment: Are you looking for global query filters? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters

Comment: Hi @Progman, I was considering using global query filters but wasn't sure of the best way to implement the toggling function of the url param includeDisabled. Any suggestions on how best to use global query filters with that in mind?

Comment: @JamesAnderbard `.IgnoreQueryFilters()` =)

Comment: @GuruStron any reason that I couldn't access the includeDisabled from the OnModelCreating and decide whether or not to include the global query filter there instead of using IgnoreQueryFilters()? My context is Scoped.

Comment: Nevermind, figured out that OnModelCreating is only run once